# Call function from sql clause: returning a variable number of columns

Tags: sql, oracle

It it possible to call a cursor returning a REF cursor from a SELECT statement?

**EDIT**
I need a variable number of returned fields, so a pipelined table is not useful for my purpose.

IE.

```
SELECT GetFields('field1, field2', flh_tout_name)
     FROM ENI_FLUSSI_HUB c
    WHERE flh_id_messaggio = '1'
```

FUNCTION GetFields(fields, vFlhToutName);
           vQuery :=
             'SELECT' || fields || ' FROM '
          || vFlhToutName;

```
  return EXECUTE IMMEDIATE (vQuery);
```

END

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so. You can create a piplined table function that you can call from a select. See my answer here [Looping on values, creating dynamic query and adding to result set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12604291/looping-on-values-creating-dynamic-query-and-adding-to-result-set/12605178#12605178)

Also see http://psoug.org/reference/pipelined.html

Basically you need to create a type that represents each row of your results. Then you create a table type which is a table of your row type.

```
CREATE TYPE MyRowType AS OBJECT(ID NUMBER, VALUE VARCHAR2(10));

CREATE TYPE MyTableType AS TABLE OF MyRowType;
```

Then your function should return MyTableType:

```
CREATE FUNCTION TestTableFunctions (lookup_Value VARCHAR2) 
RETURNS MytableType
AS
    TYPE r_cursor IS REF CURSOR;
    query_results r_cursor;
    results_out MyRowType := MyRowType(NULL, NULL);
BEGIN

OPEN query_results FOR
SELECT
    ID,
    Value
FROM
    MyTable
WHERE
    LookupValue = Lookup_Value;

LOOP
    FETCH query_results INTO 
        results_out.ID,
        results_out.Value;
    EXIT WHEN query_results%NOTFOUND;

    PIPE ROW(results_out);
END LOOP;

CLOSE query_results;
END TestTableFunctions;
```

then you can call:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE(TestTableFunctions('abcd'))
```

Comment: I need a variable number of returned fields.

Comment: @Gik25 - A variable number or a dynamic list? As in will you know all possible columns during development or can others be added? Also what type of client are you using to retrieve and process the results?

Comment: I use Toad as a client. I want to make a select field1, field2 from 'table'. But the names of columns changes from one development to the other. I can parse a dynamic query in a lot of ways and use it in a SELECT clause. But I must know the return type? I can't make a function wich returns a variable number of columns and use it as well in a SELECT statement?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include two example tables and some pseudocode of what the function should do and how you want to call it. Also when I said Client, i meant what's the application that will call this function? Is it .net or what platform?

Comment: Yes, of course. I'll do it in a few. The query will not be used by any application. I will use it from toad.